# Верно ли расставлены тире в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Суп в подвешенном над огнем котелке – жидковатое варево из тонких полосок мяса, корешков, единственной луковицы и сорванных Ирви на лесной опушке листиков кислицы – стал перекипать и переливаться через край.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Суп в подвешенном над огнем котелке – **жидковатое варево из тонких полосок мяса, корешков, единственной луковицы и сорванных Ирви на лесной опушке листиков кислицы** – стал перекипать и переливаться через край.*

Знаки расставлены верно. Вставная конструкция обособляется только двумя тире, если на месте вставки **не было никаких знаков**.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125  пункт 4(1)

При этом вставка может иметь собственные знаки: *Нас хорошо кормили, но воды – не питьевой, а для умывания – было мало.*